Not able to hide tab bar after navigating back to Login screen in KMP app
I want to hide the bottom bar as shown in attached image when i navigate back to login screen, bottom bar is added in main screen not login screen.
my main screen has tabs
 @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        TabNavigator(BrandsTab) {
            Scaffold(
                content = { CurrentTab() },
                bottomBar = {
                    BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
                        TabNavigationItem(BrandsTab)
                        TabNavigationItem(PickPlayTab)
                        TabNavigationItem(RecordingTab)
                        TabNavigationItem(SettingsTab)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }

Brand tab code:

object BrandsTab : Tab {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Navigator(screen = BrandsScreen) {
            SlideTransition(it)
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
    override val options: TabOptions
        @Composable
        get() {
            val title = "My Brands"
            val icon = painterResource(Res.drawable.ic_drive)

            return remember {
                TabOptions(
                    index = 0u,
                    title = title,
                    icon = icon
                )
            }
        }
}

in Brand screen i use this code to go back to Login screen:

        val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow
if (errorMessage?.lowercase()?.contains("expired") == true) {
                            preferenceManager.clearAuthToken()
                            navigator.replaceAll(LoginScreen)
                        }

This is what I see after navigating back to Login screen, bottom bar tabs are visible
https://i.sstatic.net/myIoa0Ds.png

I am controlling it with mutableStateOf in my AppNavHost
val bottomBarVisible = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }
and then I check the destination and if it is in the Introduction for example I change the value of mutableStateOf to false.
when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
    INTRODUCTION -> {
        topBarVisibility.value = false
        topBarBackArrowVisibility.value = false
        bottomBarVisible.value = false
    }

AdaptiveScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    topBar = {
        if (topBarVisibility.value)
            ThesisTopBar(
                backArrowVisibility = topBarBackArrowVisibility.value,
                navController = navController,
            )
    },
    bottomBar = {
        if (bottomBarVisible.value)
            BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController)
    },
) {

